# JWT : How do I renew JWT without using jwt.io

Tags: docusignapi

My DocuSign App failed the "Go Live Review" due to me not using OAuth 2.0 authentication.

I have now read the documentation on how to "Get an access token with JWT Authentication" below:

https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token/

Following this documentation I am able to get the JWT using jwt.io as suggested.

The Verified Signature code from jwt.io is then used to exchange for an DocuSign access_token using POSTMAN.

All this works as expected.

After some time the Verified Signature optained from jwt.io expires and calling https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token from POSTMAN results in this error:

{

"error": "invalid_grant",

"error_description": "expired_grant"

}

To fix this, I simply go to jwt.io and update the Payload section with new values for "iat" and "ext" and a new Verified Signature is obtained and copied in to POSTMAN for new request of access_token.

My question:

How to solve this expiring issue as DocuSign endpoint does not provide a refresh_token ?

It must be possible to somehow "renew" the Verified Signature as DocuSign endpoint requires this updated value for the field : "assertion" in POSTMAN.

I have tried to construct the three values separated by a period in the Verified Signature manually by base64 encoding, but I can´t figure out how to get the final RSASHA256 value in the Verified Signature.

I have seen the documentation for "Migrate to OAuth 2.0 using the DocuSign eSignature C#SDK" on this link :

https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/oauth2-requirements-migration/

Please note that I am not a developer and maybee the solution to my question is obvious for real developers - but I need a bit of help to solve this as I do not work in development-tool as shown on the video.

Please help...

Answer (score 2):

> How to solve this expiring issue as DocuSign endpoint does not provide a refresh_token?

The best is to create a new JWT for each OAuth call to DocuSign--and use software, not a website, to do so.

**Note:** Only obtain a new access token (by sending a fresh JWT) when the old access token has expired or is about to expire.

The DocuSign SDKs include functions to create a JWT. All of the SDKs are open source, so if you don't want to use the SDK as a whole, you can copy out the functions' implementations.

Answer (score 1):

This would depend on what language your app is written in or what kind of tool it's built on. Generally, most programming languages have libraries that can generate the JWT for you without having to use jwt.io manually.

Does your app only make API calls via postman? [This](https://dev.to/loopdelicious/using-jwt-to-authenticate-and-authorize-requests-in-postman-3a5h) post might be helpful for you. It shows how to set up a pre-request script to generate the JWT